# Menu from Views page display using contextual filter taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, navigation

Classified ads site here, Drupal 10.0.7

I have a View page display showing fields from nodes using Taxonomy Term Id as Contextual Filter.
So if the URL reads "[domain]/clasificados/8" it shows all fields of nodes tagged with term 8

How can I generate a menu from that vocabulary that points to "clasificados/{id}" ?

Taxonomy Menu generates "/taxonomy/term/{id}"

Thanks.